# Delete groups of rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df =

A          B       C
111-ABC    123    EEE
111-ABC    222    EEE
111-ABC    444    XXX
222-CCC    222    YYY
222-CCC    333    67T
333-DDD    123    TTT
333-DDD    123    BTB
333-DDD    444    XXX
333-DDD    555    AAA
```

I want to delete all groups of rows (grouped by `A`) that do not contain `123` in the column `B`.

The expected result is this one (the group of rows `222-CCC` is deleted):

```
result =

A          B       C
111-ABC    123    EEE
111-ABC    222    EEE
111-ABC    444    XXX
333-DDD    123    TTT
333-DDD    123    BTB
333-DDD    444    AAA
```

How to do it? I assume that first of all I should use `groupby`, but how to filter out the groups of rows, not just particular rows?

```
result = df.groupby("A").... ??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `query`

```
a = df.query('B == 123').A.unique()
df.query('A in @a')

         A    B    C
0  111-ABC  123  EEE
1  111-ABC  222  EEE
2  111-ABC  444  XXX
5  333-DDD  123  TTT
6  333-DDD  123  BTB
7  333-DDD  444  XXX
8  333-DDD  555  AAA
```

---

You can include additional conditions within the first `query`

```
b = df.query('B == 123 & C == "EEE"').A.unique()
df.query('A in @b')

          A    B    C
0  111-ABC  123  EEE
1  111-ABC  222  EEE
2  111-ABC  444  XXX
```

---

If speed is important.  Try this.

```
cond1 = df.B.values == 123
a = np.unique(df.A.values[cond1])
df.loc[df.A.isin(a)]
```

Comment: How can I add various conditions, e.g. by column B and C using logical OR or AND?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. This solution is much faster than the solution proposed by @Psydom. Not sure why exactly, but it works much more faster on my dataset of 1GB.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `groupby().filter()` syntax:

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda g: (g.B == 123).any())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. How can I add various conditions, e.g. by column B and C? Should it be `((g.B == 123) | (g.C == 222)).any()`?

Comment: Depending on what you need, that seems to be correct to me.

Comment: Also, `df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: 123 in x.B.values)`